# Can i know how to add this condition

Tags: apex

```
trigger VINfromAccountandContact on Case (before insert) {
    Set<id> setConids = new Set<id>();
    Map<id,id> mapAccidVsVIN = new Map<id,id>();
    for(Case c:trigger.new){
        if(c.Contactid <> NULL){
            setConids.add(c.Contactid); 
        }
    }
    if(!setConids.isEmpty()){
        for(Contact_Vehicle_Ownership__c cv :[SELECT id,Account_Name__c,Contact_Name__c,VIN_Lookup__r.id FROM Contact_Vehicle_Ownership__c WHERE Contact_Name__c IN:setConids]){
            mapAccidVsVIN.put(cv.Contact_Name__c, cv.VIN_Lookup__r.id);
        }
    }

    for(Case c:trigger.new){
        if(mapAccidVsVIN.containsKey(c.Contactid)){
            c.VIN__c = mapaccidVsVIN.get(c.Contactid);
        }
    }
}
```

can i know how can i add this condition *When accound id is not equal to null*

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where do you want to add this condition?

Comment: Sravya, please don't re-post questions if you want additional answers. Consider that if your first question isn't receiving the answer you're hoping for.. the question itself may not be clear enough and should be editted/updated with more detail.